# Вытащить все параметры из application.yaml файла

Tags: java, spring, maven, config, yaml

Всем привет!

Как многие, работающие со `Spring`, знают, что у него есть файлы конфигурации откуда можно вытаскивать настроечные параметры. В моём случае это `application.yaml`.

У меня появилась потребность в том, чтобы во время работы приложения вытаскивать из него все конфиги, которые там есть, и возвращать их куда-то там. В общем, `Controller` должен возвращать `Map` с списком всех параметров из `application.yaml`. Как это можно сделать?

Простое считывание `YAML-файла` и преобразование его в `JSON` или использование `@ConfigurationProperties` не совсем подходит, но если это единственное решение задачи, то не могли бы вы написать об этом, чтобы я хотя бы не искал других путей решения задачи.

Comment: а вам нужно именно то, что в файле? Его содержимое может быть перекрыто тем, что передано в командной строке или в файле более высокого уровня. Или всё же итоговые значения параметров?

Comment: Используете ли spring boot или нет? В spring boot это доступно из коробки с помощью actuator

Comment: Нужны итоговые значения параметров. Spring Boot использую.

Answer (score 1):

В springboot включите [actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html).

Для этого добавьте в зависимости проекта:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

После этого нужно только включить web endpoint (`env`), который показывает конфигурацию (по умолчанию он не выставляется через web). Для этого в `application.yaml` добавляем:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "health,env"
```

И теперь (если сервер слушает на порту 8080) по адресу `http://localhost:8080/actuator/env` можно увидеть всю конфигурацию, включая то, откуда параметр пришел, т.е. из какого файла, или из командной строки или из окружения и т.д.

Перед тем как это использовать в проде обязательно прочитайте доку по actuator.

Comment: он показывает все параметры, а мне нужно только из application.yaml(